# 9.5367431640625E-7という数値は何を表しているのでしょうか

Tags: php

PHPで下記コードの実行速度を測定しようと思っています。

しかし、このコードを実行すると結果が本来であれば`0`秒となると思うのですが、
`9.5367431640625E-7`秒という結果になることがあります。

**出力例**

```
test0 秒 
test9.5367431640625E-7 秒
```

こちらの数値を検索すると、MiBやKiBという単位について出てくるのですが、
この数値がたまに表示されることがある理由がわかりません。

ご存じの方いたら、教えていただきたいです。

**実行したコード**

```
<?php
$time_start = microtime(true);

echo 'test';

$time = microtime(true) - $time_start;
echo "{$time} 秒";
```

Comment: コードの最初に `ini_set('precision', 24);` を追加して実行する場合、結果に変化はありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

`9.5367431640625E-7`は一般に科学形式(科学技術形式と言ったりもする、scientific notation)と呼ばれるもので、

```
9.5367431640625 × 10の(-7)乗
```

を表しています。物理や化学の教科書にも使われているので、ご覧になったことはあると思いますが、「〜乗」を表す右肩乗せの小字(superscript)をコンピュータの文字体系の中で表すのは難しいため、

「× 10のn乗」を表す場合に、`En`と言う表記を末尾に付加します。

今回の例ですと、

```
0.0000009.5367431640625
```

を表していることになります。1マイクロ秒が`0.000001`ですから、約1マイクロ秒を表しています。

(科学形式自体は「秒」や「MiB/KiB」のような単位の情報は含んでいません。)

---

> こちらのコードを走らせると実行結果が、本来であれば、0秒となると思う

現在のあなたのコードはこのようになっています。

```
$time_start = microtime(true);          //<-ここで時刻を取得

echo 'test';                            //<- `echo 'test';`の実行にも時間がかかる

$time = microtime(true) - $time_start;  //<- ここで時刻を取得
```

と言うふうになっているので、**結果が0にならない方が当たり前** です。
(ちなみに間の`echo 'test';`がなくても、1回目の`microtime(true)`を呼ぶ瞬間と、2回目の`microtime(true)`呼ぶ瞬間との間には時間のズレがあります。)

PHPの`microtime`関数の持つ制約とPHPを実行するシステムの制約により、1マイクロ秒以下は誤差と考えてください。

---

ご質問の記述によると0秒と表示されることもあるのでしょうか。PHPの実行速度も速くなったなぁと言うのが正直なところです。ちなみに0秒と表示される場合でも、システムの時刻取得機能で取得できるほどの時間が経っていないと言うことを表しているだけで、実際の時間経過は0ではありません。

Comment: @cubick さん、あなたの編集のせいで引用部分が不必要に目立ってしまっており、どの部分をどの程度目立たせるかと言う原文の意図を大きく損なってしまっています。そんな編集を勝手に行うのはやめてください。

Comment: @OOPerさん、わかりやすい回答ありがとうございます！

Comment: @OOPer さん、行き違いがあったようであれば申し訳ありません。私はあくまで「引用箇所が(引用と)分かるように」という意図で編集を行いました。「引用部分が不必要に目立ってしまって」とありますが、これは引用によって色が変わった事を指していますか？

Comment: @cubick さん、あなたは引用を表す部分と、質問内容のどこに対する記述かを示すマーカーとの区別がつかないのでしょうか? 後者に対しては本家stackoverflowでも様々な回答者が様々に工夫して回答を書いていますし、このようなマーカーをどのように表示するかと言うお約束は本家stackoverflowにも日本語版スタックオーバーフローにもないはずです。他サイトや書籍から引用した部分と、質問内のどの部分かを示すマーカーとは厳に区別していただかないと、「引用」部分が不必要に目立ってしまい、マーキングした辺りのこと全体について論じているのに、「引用」した部分の話だけをしているように誤解されます。元回答者の意図を損なうような編集を「文言を引っ張ってきたらなんでも『引用』にする」なんて、自分の頭の中にだけ存在して何の合意もないルールで無断で行うと言うのは、モデレーターとしては好ましからざる態度だと思います。